# Convert dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy, etc to yyyymmdd in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to **convert a date format into a new format in this example is d/m/Y to Ymd,** this is how i do it in PHP with `DateTime::createFromFormat()` is there a similer function in javascript to do this?

```
    // 12/04/2012 work
    // 12/4/2012 work
    // 4/4/2012 work
    // 04/4/2012 work
    // 42/24/1234 not work

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '12/04/2012');
$train_date = $date->format('Ymd'); change the format to // 20120412
```

in short how can i do this in javascript or nodejs?

Comment: 1) Parse the incoming string into a Date object. 2) [Format the date as a string in the desired format](http://phrogz.net/js/FormatDateTime_JS.txt). With which part are you having trouble?

Comment: both? is there a datetime in javascript?

Comment: The JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) object is both date and time. A quick Google or searching this site will find you many solutions to parsing a date/time string in JavaScript.

Comment: This may helps, Have a look [Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's nice to use external libraries since node.js has a philosophy of minimal core library.
Let's have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```
var moment = require('moment');
var date = moment('12/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var train_date = date.format('YYYYMMDD');
console.log(train_date);// 20120412
```